# jQuery Flot Time missing last x-axis label

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

The problem is that when I plot a graph, the last x-axis label isn't shown on the axis (even though the value is plotted correctly).

I think I've narrowed it down to the 'minTickSize' value being 1 day, but I need it to be 1 day so I'm not sure how to get around that. I've put it in a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/s7x5ef0p/1/

JS:

```
function plotGraph(graphData){

    var graphData = [{
        data: graphData.sort(),
        color: '#FFF'
    }];

    $.plot($('#graph'), graphData, {
        series: {
            points: {
                show: true,
                radius: 5
            },
            lines: {
                show: true
            },
            shadowSize: 3
        },
        grid: {
            color: '#FFF',
            borderColor: 'transparent',
            borderWidth: 20,
            hoverable: true
        },
        xaxis: {
            mode: "time",
            timeformat: "%d/%m/%y",
            minTickSize: [1,"day"],
            tickColor: 'transparent'
        },
        yaxis: {
            tickSize: 1
        }
    });
}

var graphData = [[1430953200000,107],[1430953200000,107],    [1430953200000,107],[1430953200000,107],[1430953200000,107]
,[1430953200000,107],[1430866800000,107],[1430780400000,107]];

plotGraph(graphData);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last label would be centered at the edge of the chart and therefore extend outside the container div.
The simplest workaround is to set the max value for the x axis to a larger value so that the label can be safely placed inside the chart and container.

```
xaxis: {
    mode: "time",
    timeformat: "%d/%m/%y",
    minTickSize: [1,"day"],
    tickColor: 'transparent',
    max: 1430957400000 // max value from your data + 2 hours
},
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s7x5ef0p/2/)

Alternatively you could specify the ticks manually:

```
xaxis: {
    mode: "time",
    timeformat: "%d/%m/%y",
    ticks: [1430780400000, 1430866800000, 1430953200000],
    tickColor: 'transparent',
},
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s7x5ef0p/3/)

Comment: Thanks for you help. I played around with this, but by doing this, the value is plotted away from the end of the graph (you can see the axis line behind it). I'm not sure that it's to do with the value being too wide to fit inside the div because if you remove the 'minTickSize' value, the x-axis labels all come out as JS timestamps and extend passed the edge of the div.

Comment: Time mode handles tick labels different then default flot. See the edited answer for an alternative solution.

Comment: The updated answer solved this for me (passing ticks in manually)! Thank you!